# How to disable warnings at saving?

Tags: vba

I tried to save without warnings

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\xxx\test.xlsx", _
        ConflictResolution:=xlLocalSessionChanges
```

But still getting this `It is already exists do you want to replace` thing

How can I save and replace without warnings ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try wrapping it in an Application.DisplayAlerts = false at the start and Application.DisplayAlerts = true at the end.  Something like:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\xxx\test.xlsx", _
        ConflictResolution:=xlLocalSessionChanges

Application.DisplayAlerts= True
```

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839782(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839782%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: It's important to always set this back to true, even if the routine throws an error. [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1038115/3198973) for more info.