# How to save an Excel Workbook when the file already exists?

Tags: excel, vba

I use this macro to save my workbook:

```
sNewFilePath = ActiveWorkbook.Path

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=sNewFilePath & "/" &Range("A1")
```

But if a file already exists, and I "Cancel" or choose "No", I get VBA error. I'm new at VBA, so I cant figure out what and where to add functions to the macro to make it work...

Comment: Try searching SO based on your sample code. This looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23936601/how-to-disable-warnings-at-saving

Answer (score 0):

Using the function `Dir()` you can check if a file exist and determine what to do.

Example

```
if Dir("C:\ScrubRetValFile.txt") = "" Then
    msgbox "File not founded"
else
    msgbox "File founded"
End if
```

Cheers.