# VBA Try and Catch (MS Outlook)

Tags: vba, outlook, try-catch

I use the following function to monitor a public Outlook folder for new E-Mails to arrive:

```
Public Sub Application_Startup()

   Set NewMail = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders(3).Folders(2)....

End Sub
```

For some reason, the path to this public folder changes over time in a weekly period. What changes is the number in `.Folders(3)`. It varies from 1 to 3.
Apparently, to keep the function working and to catch the error, when the path changes, I want to implement a try and catch function such as:

```
Try {
    Set NewMail = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders(1).Folders(2)....
Catch Error

Try {
    Set NewMail = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders(2).Folders(2)....
Catch Error

Try {
    Set NewMail = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders(2).Folders(2)....
Catch Error
```

Since I am new to VBA I am struggeling implementing this Try and Catch function. Can anyone assist with VBA code in Outlook?

I think one solution I just manage to implement is:

```
For i = 1 To 3

    On Error Resume Next

    Set NewMail = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders(i).Folders(2)....

Next i
```

Comment: Does `Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders` have a `Count` property? in which case you could use `Set NewMail = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders(Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders.Count).Folders(2)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good Patterns For VBA Error Handling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038006/good-patterns-for-vba-error-handling)

Comment: You can simulate a TRY CTACH block in VBA Please see here 
http://stackoverflow.com/q/30991653/4413676

Answer (score 4):

Error handling in VBA is based on the **On Error** statement. The following articles explains how to handle errors in VBA:

- [How to Use "On Error" to Handle Errors in a Macro](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/141571)
- [Error Handling In VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm)

Try/Catch blocks is for add-ins.

Note, you can use the [NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866724.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method to get the All Public Folders folder in the Exchange Public Folders store. You just need to pass the *olPublicFoldersAllPublicFolders* value. See the sample code on the following pages:

- [Get Public Folder](http://www.outlookcode.com/codedetail.aspx?id=1164)
- [How to get reference to Public Folder Store using Outlook Object Model for Outlook 2010?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brijs/archive/2010/07/30/how-to-get-reference-to-public-folder-store-using-outlook-object-model-for-outlook-2010.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the Error by checking the Count property of the Folders Collection first, for example:

```
Set NewMail = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders(Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folder‌​s.Count).Folders(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

VB(A) does not have structured error handling, therefore it does not have try and catch statements.

If you expect a statement to fail, `On Error Resume Next` with a following `If Err.Number <> 0 Then ...` check is the way to go. It's best to keep the sections of code that are covered by `On Error Resume Next` to an absolute minimum. You don't want to silently swallow unexpected run-time errors, as this causes nasty and hard-to-find bugs.

Of course writing code in a fail-safe manner is another possibility.

Indexing into the Folders collection by number is not fail-safe, as you have noticed. Indexing numerically into an unknown collection of items should generally be avoided. Lucky for you the `Folders` collection allows indexing by name. `.Folders("Foo")` is *a lot* better than `.Folders(3)`.

Of course there might be no subfolder named `"Foo"`, but that can be handled via `On Error`.

Here is an alternative approach that uses a `path` (backslash-separated, not including the `\\Public Folders - mailbox name\All Public Folders\` part):

```
Function GetPublicFolderByPath(path As String) As Folder
  Dim parent As Folder, part As Variant

  Set parent = GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olPublicFoldersAllPublicFolders)

  For Each part In Split(path, "\")
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetPublicFolderByPath = parent.Folders(part)

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
      Set GetPublicFolderByPath = Nothing
      Exit For
    End If

    On Error GoTo 0
  Next part
End Function
```

Use like this

```
Dim f As Folder
Set f = GetPublicFolderByPath("Folder A\Folder B\Folder C")

If f Is Nothing Then
    ' not found
Else
    ' use f
End If
```

Comment: Please don't recommend `On Error Resume Next` to people. I'm sure you understand how to use it properly, but very few people actually understand how it works. Cargo cult programmers copy/paste this stuff and then wonder why their code is acting unexpectedly.

Comment: @RubberDuck If you know of *any* other way of dealing with an expected error in VBA, please enlighten me. :) Other than that - I put ample warning in my answer text. I can hardly do anything about disinterested copy/paste programmers.

Comment: Also, when recommending `On Error Resume Next` be sure that the critical `On Error Goto 0` will be executed. In your code, the `On Error Goto 0` will be skipped if the `Err.Number <> 0` condition is `true`. Moving `On Error Goto 0` to just before the `Exit For` should do the trick.

Comment: @FreeMan `On Error` has procedure scope. It will reset automatically when the Sub/Function exits.

Comment: Yeah @Tomalak. I'm aware of an *idiomatic* way to do it. We shouldn't try to force new paradigms on old languages. [This code review answer of mine](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/52231/41243) covers it pretty well.

Comment: @RubberDuck Sorry, but I don't consider `On Error Goto X` in any way better than `On Error Resume Next`. In fact, it's worse, because you have no control over which lines are allowed to fail. Been there, done that, didn't like it. (Note that I explicitly don't recommend putting `On Error Resume Next` as a global setting here, we agree that this is bad practice to say the least.)

Comment: @RubberDuck Also, about the "new paradigms on old languages" part. I don't understand what that means. I'm using a built-in, documented language feature in the way and for a task that it has been designed for. There is no "new paradigm" anywhere in my answer.

Comment: I'm not going to argue with you. It works for you. Awesome. I've just seen it bite far too many people to ever recommend `Resume Next` to anyone, ever. The CR link I shared explains that this pattern is trying very sincerely to emulate a `Try...Catch`.  That's the .Net way to do it. IMHO it's much better to do it the VB6 way while we're working in VB6. Although, I'd bash just as hard on someone using `On Error GoTo` in .Net. When in Rome, do as the Romans.

Comment: @RubberDuck Fair enough. It's a convention to use `GoTo`, and I've come to dislike it. I like my functions to crash and burn for any error condition that I did not anticipate while still allowing errors that I *did* anticipate. I even go as far as checking individual error numbers here. `On Error GoTo X` does the former, but not the latter part. I did use `On Error Resume Next` in quite a few VBA answers of mine, but never without explicit, lengthy warnings about its negative effect when used carelessly. I can't help it if people are willfully careless.

Comment: Who said anything about not checking error numbers? I do that too! Guess we'll just have to agree to disagree. ;)

Comment: You can simulate a TRY CATCH block in VBA Please see here 
http://stackoverflow.com/q/30991653/4413676