# Try catch block in Outlook Macro

Tags: vba, outlook

I had a piece of code to send data to a HTTP end point

```
Set xhr = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
xhr.Open "POST", URL, False
xhr.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Data = "volumeDate=" & URLEncode(VolumeDate) & "&" & "volume=" & URLEncode(Volume)
xhr.Send Data
```

I want to have a try catch block to handle if it didnt connect to the URL or if it returned something apart from a 200

How do I do it?

Comment: Try/Catch is not available in VBA. [Here's a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30188584/vba-try-and-catch-ms-outlook).

Comment: VBA has error handling, and/or you can check the `status` of the response.  VBA is not VB.Net or some other language though, so you need to do a bit of Googling on VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error handling in VBA is based on the `On Error` statement. Take a look at the [Error Handling In VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm) for more information.

I'd suggest creating a COM add-in instead of VBA macros. You will be able to check the error code easily and handle exceptions gracefully. See [Walkthrough: Creating Your First VSTO Add-In for Outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to get started quickly.