# How to hide sheets in an Excel workbook based on the tab names in a table

Tags: excel, google-sheets, hide, vba

I have a table called "HideSheets" (single column) to which sheets get added or sometimes removed. How do I reference the table in

```
Sub HideSheets()
    Dim cell As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each cell In Sheets("Index").Range("HideSheets")
        ' Hide sheets
        Sheets(cell.Value).Visible = False

End Sub
```

Comment: `For Each` must also have a `Next` at the bottom of the code to be looped (I.e just before `End Sub`)

Answer (score 2):

`For Each` must also have a `Next` command

```
Sub HideSheets()
    Dim r As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each r In Sheets("Index").Range("HideSheets")
        ' Hide sheets
        Sheets(r.Value).Visible = xlSheetHidden
    Next r
End Sub
```

Rather than using `On Error Resume Next`, check for conditions which might cause an error and deal with them appropriately. For example, return an error to the user which explains that the following error(s) have occurred:

1. User attempted to hide *all* sheets in a workbook
2. `r.Value` is not a valid sheet name.

Comment: Further reading on error handling here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038006/good-patterns-for-vba-error-handling