# VBA error handler: On Error Resume does not work in the handler

Tags: vba, error-handling

In Excel VBA, I open a Word app and a doc inside.
I want to make sure the doc and Word are closed at the end, even if there was an error.

I created an error handler with `On Error GoTo ErrorHandler`, that works. But there `objDoc.Close` fails when the doc was not opened (Runtime error 424), and the Sub is aborted before `objWord.Quit` although I called `On Error Resume Next`.

Why does `On Error Resume Next` not work there?

(In VBA options, Error Trapping is set to "Break on Unhandled Errors".)

```
Sub test()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    ' Open doc in Word
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    objWord.Visible = False
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("not a valid doc.docx")

    ....

    ' Save and exit
    objDoc.Save
    objDoc.Close
    objWord.Quit
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & vbLf & Err.Description
    On Error Resume Next
    ' Exit
    objDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
    objWord.Quit
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: `On Error` statements aren't supposed to be executed in an error state...

Comment: The generally used pattern for stuff like this is to `Resume` to a label where you do your cleanup - like where `' Save and exit` is.

Comment: See [Good Patterns For VBA Error Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1038006/4088852) - it's worth a read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how I would do it, like @Comintern says

```
Sub test()
    Dim objWord As Object
    Dim objDoc As Object

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    ' Open doc in Word
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    objWord.Visible = False
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("not a valid doc.docx")




ErrExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    objDoc.Save
    objDoc.Close
    objWord.Quit
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & vbLf & Err.Description
    Resume ErrExit
End Sub
```

That `Resume` statement gets you out of the error state and allows you to reset an error trap.

Comment: Upvoted; I would only add that the variables should be explicitly declared, and the double-dot referencing of `objWord.Documents` is leaking the implicit collection object, which means OP probably has a bunch of WINWORD.EXE ghost processes in their task manager (see my deleted answer)