# Automation Error when Attempting to Query Access Database Using VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access, adodb

I've made the following ADODB object declarations in code.

```vb
Dim OConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim fld As ADODB.Field
Set OConn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
```

I would like to use the following code to read from a table on a MS Access database file and generate a recordset, rs.

```vb
'Get the table name from the search results.
tableName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PLC Module Data").Cells(2, 9).Value

'Set the SQL string.
strSql = "SELECT Code, Points, Type, Description, Rating " & _
"FROM " & tableName

'Set the connection string and open the connection to the Access DB.
OConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
"Data Source=Q:\AutoCAD Improvements\PLC IO Utility Docs\PLC IO Spreadsheet     
App\PLC IO App\ace_plc.mdb"

OConn.Open

'Open the recordset and error out if nothing is returned
Set rs = OConn.Execute(strSql)
If rs.EOF Then
    MsgBox "No matching records found."
    rs.Close
    OConn.Close
    Exit Sub
End If
```

I've checked the query statement within the Access file itself and it works fine. I always get the error

> Run-time error'-2147217900 (80040e14)': Automation Error

on the line,

```vb
Set rs = OConn.Execute(strSql)
```

If anyone could take a look over my code and determine why this is happening it would be much appreciated. I've looked at similar examples online and it seems like this should be correct.

Comment: Have you checked that `tableName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PLC Module Data").Cells(2, 9).Value` is the right table name? What does it return?

Comment: What does the SQL resolve to?  Also, have you tried, `rs.open strSQL,oconn.connection`

Comment: Just in case, I'd put the field names in []: `"SELECT [Code], [Points], [Type], [Description], [Rating] "`

Comment: Try this for your SQL string: `strSql = "SELECT a.Code, a.Points, a.Type, a.Description, a.Rating FROM [" & tableName & "] AS a"` Then add `Debug.Print strSql` on the next line.  If you still get an error using this version, please show us what `Debug.Print` shows you.

Comment: check that oConn is actually open by using If Oconn.state <> adstateopen then msgbox "Not Open"

Comment: Is there anything going on in this database, like compacting/repairing deleting/reimporting data?

Comment: Cannot reproduce issue. Please use proper [error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038006/good-patterns-for-vba-error-handling) and report specific runtime error and message.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback. @HansUp, it turns out all I needed were the brackets around the tableName string as you suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added the brackets around the tableName string and it works now. Thanks for all the feedback.

```
'Set the SQL string.
strSql = "SELECT Code, Points, Type, Description, Rating " & _
"FROM [" & tableName & "]"
```