# For each (except for the dodgy bits)

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to build a macro for Word that will go through every table and remove any line spacing from the text and then resize the tables to match.

I have the following code:

```
For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
    For Each r In tbl.Rows
        r.SetHeight RowHeight:=0.1, HeightRule:=wdRowHeightAtLeast
    Next
Next
```

However this returns

> Run-time error '5991': "Cannot access individual rows in this
>   collection because the table has vertically merged cells."

on the line `For Each r In tbl.Rows`

The merged cells are in the two-row-header of the table so I'm happy to ignore them in the process. How then would I do a `For Each` that skips the first two values of `tbl.Rows`?

Comment: You could try catching the error and just ignoring the line on the error.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038006/good-patterns-for-vba-error-handling for an example of this.

Comment: I've tried putting `On Error Resume Next` in at various points within the code however it either skips the table altogether or the bug still appears. It seems that the issue is not setting the row height for a merged cell but rather in setting aside the list of values for `r`.

Comment: If you want to ignore the first couple of rows then you can do something like `For i = 3 to tbl.Rows.Count` then work with `tbl.Rows(i)`

Comment: Any reason you couldn't do: `tbl.Rows.SetHeight RowHeight:=0.1, _ 
 HeightRule:=wdRowHeightAtLeast`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you set the rows for the whole table at once?

```
For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
    tbl.Rows.SetHeight RowHeight:=0.1, HeightRule:=wdRowHeightAtLeast
Next
```