# Trying to create a file save as routine that pulls info from date and uses it in file name

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a save as VBA routine that takes a date on the page, breaks the date down into its component parts and uses those parts to create the file's name and to save the file in a folder that also uses the date information.

This is what I came up with, but it fails at the save section and i think it is because i have something wrong with the path construction.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Jeremy

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test_Save()

    Dim folderPath      ' Sets path to onedrive
    Dim fPath           ' Establishes default root file location
    Dim fName           ' Establishes file name variable
    Dim fExtension      ' Establishes default file extension
    Dim fullfName       ' Used to combine the data into the save path
    Dim MoNum           ' Establishes month number variable
    Dim DayNum          ' Establishes date number variable
    Dim MoName          ' Establishes month name variable
    Dim YearNum         ' Establishes year number variable

    ' Establishes folder path
    
    folderPath = Environ$("ONEDRIVE") & "\Documents\Old Documents\"

    ' Extracts data from date range
    
    DayNum = Format(Day(Range("B13")), "dd")                        ' Extracts the two-digit day number
    MoNum = Format(Month(Range("B13")), "mm")                       ' Extracts the two-digit month number
    MoName = Format(Month(Range("B13")), "mmmm")                    ' Extracts the name of the month
    YearNum = Year(Range("B13"))                                    ' Extracts the four-digit year

    ' Establishes full path and file name

    fPath = folderPath & YearNum & " Work\"                         ' Sets path to file location
    fName = "Line-ups " & MoNum & "-" & DayNum & "-" & YearNum      ' Creates the file name
    fExtension = ".xlsm"                                            ' Creates the desired extension
    fullfName = fPath & fName & fExtension                          ' Combines the file name and extension
    
    ' Saves the file
    
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=fullFName, FileFormat:= _
        xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: Knowing what error is being shown would be helpful.

Comment: You should change `DayNum = Format(Day(Range("B13")), "dd")` to `DayNum = Format(Range("B13"), "dd")`, `MoNum = Format(Month(Range("B13")), "mm")` to `MoNum = Format(Range("B13"), "mm")`, and `MoName = Format(Month(Range("B13")), "mmmm")` to `MoName = Format(Range("B13"), "mmmm")`. You should also make sure the fully qualified path exists which is probably where your failure point is. Neither the FSO object or ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs will create the fully qualified path.

Comment: Do you already have the folders created, or are you expecting the macro to create the folders? The macro will not create them automatically, you would have to write code to create the folders & subfolders

Comment: Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70851115/saving-excel-files-in-a-new-folder

Comment: The folders have already been created, and the use the format ```\Old Work\2024 Work\01 January\``` format.

Comment: The error is ```Runtime error 76, Path not found``` I am really trying to use environmental variables instead of an absolute path, hence the ```Environ$("ONEDRIVE")``` statement.